# Generating a numpy array using information from two other arrays

Tags: python

I have the two following numpy arrays:

```
initial_array = np.array ([2, -10, 3, 5, 4])
indicator array = np.array([1, 3, 2, 3])
```

I want to generate a new numpy array which looks into the indicator array in order to extract values from the intial_array. The solution should look like this:

```
final_array =  [ 2  3  -10   3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a programming than a data science question, but you can simply use the `indicator_array` to index the `initial_array` after subtracting 1 since arrays are zero indexed:

```
import numpy as np

initial_array = np.array ([2, -10, 3, 5, 4])
indicator_array = np.array([1, 3, 2, 3])

initial_array[indicator_array - 1]
# array([  2,   3, -10,   3])
```